# Losing object reference in Javascript with await

Tags: javascript

I was learning the event loop of JavaScript and tried to run this function:

```js
async function foo() {
    console.log('FIrst');
    let a = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        console.log("inside Promise");
        resolve();
    })
    console.log(a);
    console.log('Second');
} 
foo();
console.log('Three');
```

On running this code gave output as follows:

```
FIrst
inside Promise
Three
undefined
Second
```

I am not able to understand why the variable `a` lost its value (the object assignment). I have searched for this behavior but was not able to understand from the answers.
Please may someone explain the order of execution which results in this output?

Comment: It never _had_ a reference-- because you are using `await`, `a` will not contain a reference to the promise-- it will contain whatever is resolved out from the promise it is awaiting.

Comment: @pilchard `Promise.resolve()` creates a new promise with the value supplied. The resolver parameter for the executor is described [in the constructor section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise)

Comment: "*why did `a` lose its value (the object assignment)*" - uh, you never assigned an object to `a`? What object did you expect to be logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `await` the newly created promise, you're not assigning the promise to `a`, you're assigning the resolve value of it.

```js
async function foo() {
    let a = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // This is where the value stems from
        resolve(42);
    });
    console.log(a);
} 
foo();
```

If you want to keep the `await` while also retrieving the reference, you can separate those two steps:

```js
async function foo() {
    let a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(42);
    });
    await a;
    console.log(a instanceof Promise);
} 
foo();
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, I was confused and thought this has something to do with jobs in microtask queue

Comment: Hey @Etheryte is there a way I can get `a` assigned to a promise and not the resolve value while not keeping await?
Like a might return Promise as pending

Comment: @Tinfinity That would be the second option and removing the `await a`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because if you are using `await` it returns to `a` variable the thing that you've passed in `resolve`, so you didn't pass any value in resole this is why it is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the promise's value is undefined is because you did not set the value that the promise should output. If you want the promise to return something other than undefined, place an expression or string inside the resolve() function. If you want the promise to return "Promise completed" after it resolves and console.log the result, simply use the code

```
async function foo() {
    let a = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        resolve("Promise completed");
    })
    console.log(a);
} 
foo();
```